# How convert curl call into java HttpPost: curl --form "archive=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf"

Tags: java, http, curl, httprequest

How convert curl call into java HttpPost:

```
curl --form "archive=@test.pdf;type=application/pdf"
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem
below the solution I used:

```
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(resourceURL);
    MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    File file = new File(doc.getPath());

    entity.addPart("title", new StringBody(doc.getTitre()));
    entity.addPart("file", new StringBody(doc.getTag()));
    entity.addPart("archive", new FileBody((file), "type=application/pdf"));

    httpPost.setEntity(entity);
```